# Color does not change corresponding the radio checked in Pure CSS Tab Layout

Tags: html, css

I want to make a tab layout from **only HTML and CSS**, without any JavaScript/jQuery or another things, I had seen some tutorials in the internet like [this one](https://codepen.io/Wendy-Ho/pen/MWWBvmd). However, the color change according to the current tab does not work. I don't know what is wrong on my code that caused such problem. What is literally wrong from my code below? Any inputs/recommendation/correction are highly appreciated. Thank you.

```css
.restaurant-detail__tabs {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 70px auto;
}

.restaurant-detail__tabs-labels {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
}

.restaurant-detail__tabs-label {
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.restaurant-detail__tabs-label:hover,
label:hover {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.restaurant-detail__tabs__tab-content {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 2px solid #aaa;
}

input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

#tab1:checked ~ #tab-content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #tab-content2 {
    display: block;
}

#tab1:checked ~ #li-label1,
#tab2:checked ~ #li-label2 {
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: red;
    color: red;
}

#tab1:checked ~ #label1,
#tab2:checked ~ #label2 {
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: red;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="restaurant-detail__tabs">
    <input type="radio" checked name="tabs" id="tab1" />
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2" />
    <ul class="restaurant-detail__tabs-labels" role="tablist">
        <li class="restaurant-detail__tabs-label" id="li-label1">
            <label for="tab1" id="label1">Menu</label>
        </li>
        <li class="restaurant-detail__tabs-label tab2" id="li-label2">
            <label for="tab2" id="label2">Reviews</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-content1" class="restaurant-detail__tabs__tab-content">
        This is Menu
    </div>
    <div id="tab-content2" class="restaurant-detail__tabs__tab-content">
        <div class="restaurant-detail__review">
            <div class="restaurant-detail__review-items">
                This is Review
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify `ul` in the selector of access to `li`, with the status `:checked`. Because the `~` operator is valid at the **current level** of elements, but not for children.

Like that:

```
#tab1:checked ~ ul #li-label1,
#tab2:checked ~ ul #li-label2 {
    ...
}
```

> The general sibling combinator `(~)` separates two selectors and matches all iterations of the second element, that are following the first element (though not necessarily immediately), and are children of the same parent element.

```css
.restaurant-detail__tabs {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 70px auto;
}

.restaurant-detail__tabs-labels {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
}

.restaurant-detail__tabs-label {
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.restaurant-detail__tabs-label:hover,
label:hover {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.restaurant-detail__tabs__tab-content {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 2px solid #aaa;
}

input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

#tab1:checked ~ #tab-content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #tab-content2 {
    display: block;
}

#tab1:checked ~ ul #li-label1,
#tab2:checked ~ ul #li-label2 {
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}

#tab1:checked ~ #label1,
#tab2:checked ~ #label2 {
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: red;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="restaurant-detail__tabs">
    <input type="radio" checked name="tabs" id="tab1" />
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2" />
    <ul class="restaurant-detail__tabs-labels" role="tablist">
        <li class="restaurant-detail__tabs-label" id="li-label1">
            <label for="tab1" id="label1">Menu</label>
        </li>
        <li class="restaurant-detail__tabs-label tab2" id="li-label2">
            <label for="tab2" id="label2">Reviews</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-content1" class="restaurant-detail__tabs__tab-content">
        This is Menu
    </div>
    <div id="tab-content2" class="restaurant-detail__tabs__tab-content">
        <div class="restaurant-detail__review">
            <div class="restaurant-detail__review-items">
                This is Review
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```